# 蘇 (Su) surname Generation Poem

Tags: characters, word, websites, surnames

My name is John Su. I am came from an Indonesian speaking family, not a Chinese a speaking one. I need to know of an English or Malay or at least a mixed language website that tell exactly the Generation-Poem of the Su surname? Thank-you in advance for your kind help.

Comment: my name is Minh Su. Unlike you, I'm Vietnamese; but similar to you, I'm of Chinese lineage and hoping to learn more from our generational poem (maybe it's the same one). Have you had the chance to learn more? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Generation poems are specific to a particular male line of a family, rather than everyone sharing a surname.  Unless one of your ancestors along the male line decided to choose a generation poem, you won't have one - but that is quite normal!

More information in English: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_name#Generation_poem

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a generation poem for Su. Generation poems typically have a limited number of characters. Once the characters are run out, an elder member of the family might choose another generation poem. The shorter the poem, the closer the family members. A friend of mine has a generation poem of 本支百世。So, people who use this generation poem are no more than four generations away.

Generation poem typically can be found in the family's genealogy record. If you or your family have one, you can consult it. If not, you may want to find out the names of your elder members in your family. A good place to find is an ancestral hall. From the names, there is a chance you might be able to extract the generation poem.